# How to pass javacsript variable to vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have simple script in javascript to get selected text. (In my case does not work vue to get it from that select... - because there is jquery mobile, which change many things at site). And after I want to use that value in vue (automatically save to data for example...).

Here is part of html:

```
<select onchange="val(this)" id="RKStroj" data-native-menu="false" data-fieldname="X_RK_stroj_ID" data-rolltable="(select X_vyrobne_cislo code, name,id  from storecards where hidden='N' and x_typ_zariadenia is not null ) A">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo - 24</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab - 48</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes - 72</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi - 92</option>
</select>
```

Here is script and part of vue:

```
<script>
   function val(sel) {
      var mySelected;
      mySelected = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

      const last2 = mySelected.slice(-2);
      console.log(last2); 

      document.getElementById("demo").value=this.value = last2; 
// using this line of code I am able to send it to input, where I have v-model="numb"... but every time I have to click there and change it to save value to vue


   }

var app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
       checkbox: false,
       numb: 0,
       message: ''
       
     },
     methods: {
     ..........
     },



     
   })
   
       </script>
```

What is the best way how to get javasript value "last2" and rewrite vue.js value "numb" from zero...?
Or what are options how to do it? create method for it? I just to start to learning vue, so I am still new here. In this case I am using vue2 :)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to mix JavaScript and Vue? Vue should generally just render the whole page. The element you are trying to get should be a Vue component instead. I believe you could do `window.last2 = ...` and get that variable from Vue as well but that's a bit weird. The goal should be to use Vue all the way.

Comment: Even though it's a common use for Vue to use it for a whole page (SPA), it's not necessary. But at least a part of it you work with should be controlled by Vue (consider it a widget). It's a mistake to mix jQuery and Vue, most time this indicates that a dev is uncomfortable with Vue enough to do this with Vue alone, and this results in unconventional problems that wouldn't happen otherwise and require some skills to solve, so it's a really bad approach for Vue newbies. Just don't do this, refactor a self-sufficient portion of the page to use Vue only.

Comment: Thanks guys, in this case unfortunately I am not able to remake web to vue. But i just want to use vue for some new addons. Everything what I need is just how to pass variable to vue. (I still thinking about that possiblity how to catch that value added to input from javascript. It is possible to focus in input and change it? (for saving purposes...)

Comment: If you can't rebuild the web to Vue - then you need https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element

Comment: For now my problem is partially solved by adding button with `@click="change"`, and adding `ref="inputField"` to my input,  and creating method `change () {
         this.numb = this.$refs.inputField.value
      },`
Maybe for others in future it will be usefull. - useful info - [vue get input value](https://codingbeautydev.com/blog/vue-get-input-value/)